# Embedded Terminology for Consecutive Register Retrieval

Tags: embedded, terminology

**Resolved**

I have a question about terminology used in embedded systems.

What is the term that is used when requesting the content of multiple consecutive registers from a peripheral device?

(The term that I was looking for was Burst-Read and Burst-Write.)

For example the I2C pseudo-class below demonstrates the retrieval of a range of registers beginning from a (base-address) all the way to (base address + count). What term would you used to express this?

```
 Class I2C{

 void getConsecutiveRegister( address base, int count, Integer[] inportValues){...}

 void getRegister( address base, Integer value){
         getConsecutiveRegister(base, 1, value);
      }

 }
```

Comment: Specific technologies have official designations for particular efficient access mechanisms (burst mode access, I2C auto-increment reads, SMBus block reads, etc) but doubt there is any single commonly agreed upon term for the general concept. Judging by the pseudo-code you seem to be looking for a term for the opposite case though, chaining a block read out of multiple discrete transactions. I might perhaps describe that case as a segmented block read, though I am perhaps alone in it.

Comment: you might call it a bank of registers.  But there is no standard terms for such things, really most things dont have standard terms, the buzz words come from specific fields sometimes specific companies sometimes specific departments within a company.   is it a GPIO, or a DIO or a PIO?  is spi mosi/miso or simo/somi or just d0,d1,d2,d3, etc...sometimes the term register file is used as well...

Comment: for i2c I would go with where doynax was going.  You are just doing a burst read from address n to address m.  or a read of M bytes starting at address N.

Comment: doynax - Thank you!
The term that I was looking for was Burst-Read and Burst-Write.

Answer (score 0):

There is, as far as I know, no formal term for the request of several registers.

Several consecutive registers on adjacent addresses is formally called a register map. This mostly refers to hardware peripheral registers getting memory mapped in a microcontroller's memory, but the term is used broadly for any collection of registers where each register has an address.

So I would perhaps call the function `getRegisterMap` or similar.